# PHP regex preg_match to identify url pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Is there any way to make rule allow only example 1 and 3 and not all 4 of them?

```
/^(en\/|)([\d]{1,3})([-])(.+?)([\/])$/
```

**examples:**

1. 12-blog/
2. 12-blog/blog2/
3. en/12-blog/
4. en/12-blog/blog2/

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/tFe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use an optional part for `en/` followed by match 1-3 digits, `-` and match not a `/` 1+ times using a negated character class.

Note that you can omit the square brackets for `[\d]`, `[-]` and `[\/]`. If you choose a different delimiter than `/` you don't have to escape the forward slash.

```
^(?:en/)?\d{1,3}-[^/]+/$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:en/)?` Optionally match `en/`
- `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
- `-` Match literally
- `[^/]+/` Match 1+ times any char except `/`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YNTHFw/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/DpbTI)